# How do I add multiple shape masks to my canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I am trying to add multiple shape masks to an image. I call a function that takes in the coordinates and draws a shape square on screen. This square reveals part of the image. This works fine one time. After that, it is not redrawn. What I want to happen is that I draw several shapes/masks on the screen to eventually reveal the entire image.

```
    var baseImg;
    var ctx;
    var img;
    var imageLoaded = false;
    var gridWidth = 50;
    var gridHeight = 50;

    function init() {
        baseImg = $('#baseImg')[0];
        ctx = baseImg.getContext('2d');
        img = new Image();
        imageLoaded = false;

        img.onload = function() {
            imageLoaded = true;
        }
        img.src = './images/tiles.jpg';
    };

    function showMask(maskCoord){
        if(!imageLoaded) return;

        var originPoint = {
            x : (gridWidth * maskCoord.x),
            y : (gridHeight * maskCoord.y)
        }

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(originPoint.x, originPoint.y);
        ctx.lineTo((originPoint.x + gridWidth), originPoint.y);
        ctx.lineTo((originPoint.x + gridWidth), (originPoint.y + gridHeight));
        ctx.lineTo(originPoint.x, (originPoint.y + gridHeight));
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.clip();

        /// draw the image to be clipped
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
```

Here is a link to what I am doing.

http://jsfiddle.net/DezOnlyOne/CLYNA/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you clip, you reduce the area that can be drawn to the provided path. And since two grid cells do not intersect at all, clipping on more than one cell will give empty result.

Solution is to 'cancel' previous clipping before the next draw : save() and restore() are two function that allow you to save the context at some point then to restore it to full 'clean' original state after the draw.

http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/CLYNA/7/

```
function showMask(maskCoord) {
    if (!imageLoaded) return;
    var originPoint = {
        x: (gridWidth * maskCoord.x),
        y: (gridHeight * maskCoord.y)
    }
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(originPoint.x, originPoint.y, gridWidth, gridHeight);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();
    /// draw the image to be clipped
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: Thanks GameAlchemist!

Comment: @Loktar I sometimes do i guess... Anyway thanks mate !